# Woocommerce: Get Cart ID

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Can i get the cart id and instanciate the cart later?

In another case, is there a unique identifier that I can use to store information from each cart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why this question down-voted? I think it is can be very useful. Unfortunately WooCommerce have not feature like this. But you can:

1. Set cookie with unique id, when user added something to cart
2. Create db table with `cookie_cart_id` and items, and update this table when user change items in cart.
3. When user create order - delete cookie